# What design pattern is better when I want to abstract interprocess communication?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a class which communicates with other process with my socket library. But soon, some of my team members will release another socket library. So I have to replace socket communication module with it.

So I want to abstract the communication way with a design pattern. In such situation, what design pattern is better for me? My class shouldn't access my socket library directly.

Comment: its' my fault. I have to use abstraction, not obstacle.

Comment: ACE is used (among other systems) by the Facebook Android app. The following document explains (I think) your problem and discusses solutions in C++ as well as how ACE works. https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/netcomp.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Stop thinking sockets. Think interprocess communication API. Otherwise you will design an abstraction which is too low level.

What do you really want to do? Send application messages between processes? Send notifications?

Create a higher level abstraction instead. Something like:

```
public interface ICommunicationChannel
{
    ApplicationMessage Receive();
    void Send(ApplicationMessage);
    event EventHandler<FailureEventArgs> ChannelFaulted;
}
```

.. or, if your messages should be pushed from the other end point:

```
public interface ICommunicationChannel
{
    void Send(ApplicationMessage);
    event EventHandler<FailureEventArgs> ChannelFaulted;
    event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;
}
```

By doing it on that level you have a loose coupling with the communication layer and are free to design it using whatever technology you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a ProcessCommuniactionInterface. 
This interface should expose the basic operations and send() , receive(), callback() etc as per your need.

Right now it will have one implementation as say SocketLib1ProcessCommuniactionImpl .

Later on when any other Lib comes up , add one more implementation as SocketLib2ProcessCommuniactionImpl.

How you migrate would depend on your usecase:

1. If the use case is to completely drop using 1st one and start using the second one , you could directly replace the first Implementation with the second one. (Most of the organizations don't go for this as it is risky and can lead to rollback)
2. If the use case is to use on Lib for some flows and other Lib for other flow (This will most likely be case when some processes you communicate with are using Lib1 and others are using lib2) ,you should keep both implementations.  Here there are two cases:
       a. the flows are fixed when we have to use lib1 and when to use lib2 . Go for a static config file , and get the data from there and call the respective implemtation.
       b. we need the ability to dynamically use one of the libraries. Go for something like Strategy Pattern here.

Hope this helps:)